# Selected radio button value not passing with postback data in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I used Html.RadioButtonFor for item selection in list but it causes name attribute conflict. here is my sample model

```
public class DataList {
     public List<Videos> { set; get;}
}

public class Videos {
    public int isSelected {set; get;}
    public int id {set; get;}
    public string Title { set; get;}
    ---
}
```

View template will look like this

```
@for (var i = 0; i <= Model.DataList.Count - 1; i++)
{
       <label class="radio">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m =>Model.Videos[i].isSelected, Model.Videos[i].id)</label>
}
```

But this cause name attribute conflict (multiple options selected instead of single)

Can anyone help me fix this problem.

Comment: easiest approach would be to use checkboxes.. and javascript to uncheck other boxes

Comment: Unclear what your trying to do with this. You giving each radio button `name="Item.isDefault"` which has no relationship to your model (so nothing will be bound when you submit). Then `isDefault` is typeof `int` but your setting the value of the buttons to either `true` or `false` (again it can't be bound). What are you actually trying to bind to?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Its sample code i want someone help me. i use alternative approach but there should be a way to bind radio buttons with data list just like we bind checkboxes for check / uncheck features. if you have idea then please post answer and give me and other people idea how to do it.

Comment: The code you have shown makes no sense. From your edit, I'm guessing you want to bind to the property `bool Selected` (or maybe `bool Default`?) but you really need to explain what your trying to achieve

Comment: @StephenMuecke did you implement checkbox to check uncheck all items in a list? if yes i want that but using radio button instead  of checkbox (to select only one option), just imagine i am building a poll or questionair app. if you have any example then post it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke your post is good but i was facing issue when posting data back to server. i posted answer to my own question which will logically show you where i face problem and now fixed my issue. i actually misjudge radiobuttonfor usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My issue fixed by shifting isSelected attribute from list to model as only one option selected at a time therefore no need to use within list.

Modified model will look like this.

```
public class DataList {
     public int isSelected {set; get;}
     public List<Videos> Videos { set; get;}
}

public class Videos {
    public int id {set; get;}
    public string Title { set; get;}
    ---
}
```

Modified view will look like this

```
@for (var i = 0; i <= Model.DataList.Count - 1; i++)
{
       <label class="radio">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m =>Model.isSelected, Model.Videos[i].id)</label>
}
```

Now this code works fine perfectly with both radio button selection and posting data.

Comment: If a user selects one of your radio buttons it can never be unselected unless you also have `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DataList[counter].Default, false)`

Comment: yes post works fine but selection cause problem due to name attribute conflict. i mentioned post which fixed my issue by using select property outside list<data>

Comment: Oh dear. It has nothing to do with `name` attribute conflict. And the answer you linked to does not change the `name` attribute. You need to do some more research to understand what a html radio button is.

Comment: ok don't know why you not understand my issue. now i updated by question and answer which fixed my issue.

Comment: You post a question which made no sense and included code that had absolutely no relationship at all to your question. Then you post an answer which made even less sense and you wonder why no one understands it or gives you an answer? You have now completely changed both the question and the answer (which now does make sense)

Comment: sorry same issue was before but i posted in a different way, now posted in much easier way.

Comment: This guy seems to be posting questions, then getting answers from people, but still answers his own problem with what he learned from the answers and accepts his own answer. Really classy way to gain reputation! 1800 of his rep is a question I answered, he copied that answer and accepted. Ah well... So be it...

Comment: @patrick i don't need stackoverflow reputation even i have no time to come and browse stackoverflow. if someone not given good answer why i will mark as answer. tell stackoverflow community to remove feature (marking our own answer as best question). if you want i will give you my all reputation.

Comment: @patrick if you have any good solution for my issue, post your anwer. i will   mark as best answer and other people will get benefit from it and will upvote. if not then don't bark.

Answer (score 1):

Since the input controls are generated on item object instead of bound Model expression; due to the incorrect expression, name of controls are generated appropriately in html. That's why on post back the value will not be passed to server in ModelState. I have corrected your view code. Please refer below:

```
@{ 
    var counter = 0;
}
@foreach (var Item in Model.DataList)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
              @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DataList[counter].LanguageID)
              @Item.CultureName
        </td>
        <td>
              @if (Item.isDefault == 1)
              {
                  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DataList[counter].isDefault, Model.DataList[counter].Default, new { @checked = "checked" })
              }
              else
              {
                 @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DataList[counter].isDefault, Model.DataList[counter].Default, new { })
              }
       </td>
   </tr>

  counter++;
}
```

Comment: actually problem arise, it generate name attribute as name="DataList[1].isDefault" , in radio button case it should be similar for all radio elements.

Comment: Yes, the generated name should be like "DataList[0].isDefault", "DataList[1].isDefault", "DataList[2].isDefault" and so on....

Comment: Yes but in this case radio group will not be created. need a way to create group of radio buttons and also make compatible with listing model.

Comment: radio button inside a group should have only unique name for ex : "DataList[0].isDefault", If names are not unique in group then those input controls would not part of group.

Comment: The second parameter is the value of radio button so if the value of expression and value provided is same then radio button will be selected automatically. Otherwise you can use the extension `@Html.RadioButton` instead of `@Html.RadioButtonFor` as it gives you option to set the radio button as selected.

Answer (score -1):

You can use checkboxes and get the same user interface as radio buttons. You just need to add some javascript to unselect the other checkboxes.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.DataList.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.DataList[i].LanguageID)
            @Model.DataList[i].CultureName
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.DataList[i].Default, new { @class="check-radio" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.check-radio').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.check-radio').prop("checked", false);
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Asking the OP to use checkboxes with javascript instead of radio buttons is really bad advice.(I'm just being salty)

Comment: @hatcyl yeah god forbid OP learn the right way to easily manage a collection of items