# checked property of a radio button not binding to boolean property of a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Below is i have radio button set up. I have Configuration as group name, and i have 4 different radio buttons in this group which have different selectionId and i bound 3rd option which is checked property to Boolean Selection. I am able to bind checked property to selection from database when i do get method. but when i select the radio button i want to turn selection to true which is not happening for me to model bind it to save  method and save that selection in database. Each Model in list will have same ConfigurationName.

```
@model List<Model>
    <form method="post" asp-action="Configure" novalidate>

      @foreach (var x in Model)
                {
        @Html.RadioButton(x.Configuration,
                    x.SelectionId,
                    x.Selection,
                    new { id = x.SelectionId })
    }

     <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
        </form>
```

Controller Method

```
     [HttpPost]
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Configure(List<Model> modellist)
            {
              //will have have to write save logic here, but first my model does not get value of selection as true when that radio button is clicked
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

Comment: please provide the controller method as well, what are you saying is that you are checking the radio button and on the controller you are not receiving the value(true or false) to save it into the database?

Comment: just added it @Zinov

Comment: yes. it always giving me false value to the controller method.

Comment: here you will find your answer https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ see the indexes you need to create on the name property of the html tag in order to retrieve it as a list on the controller. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The Radio button would post back the selected value only which would not be a boolean value.

Perhaps you can have a complex model in the POSt action where you can have the list as a property (instead of the actual model) and then another property to get the selected radio button as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33464014/218408